# It is possible to hide comments on a Facebook Page by Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently, Facebook Graph API is supporting us:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/comment/

With Updating permission: is_hidden to hide comment.
It'll check the attribute "can_hide" to hide or not.

But why does the "can_hide" always return "false"? So Facebook API can't hide the comment.

Is there solution for hide the Facebook comment?

Comment: Did you use an access token with the correct permissions?

Comment: Yes i did. This about "can_hide" is alway true, so I can't hide comment

Comment: I just checked for a page I have admin access to, and I get can_hide=true for all comments on the page’s posts. Perhaps something to do with the page settings, so I’d start by checking those.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation. That mean I can hide the comment.
Please help me to check your page setting. I trying find but not found.

Comment: @CBroe: Can you hide a comment by Facebook API?